# how to set object key/value pair to initial state in vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

In my application, I am creating an object to store key/value pair for static texts and passing to the initial state. But, it is showing an error.

Here is my `helpers.js`:

```
    export const translation = Object.freeze({
        edit: 'Edit',
        please_select_text: 'Please select a row to edit',
        done: 'Done',
        role: 'Role',
});
```

Now I am importing this in my store module and passing like this:

```
const defaultState = () => ({
       localized: translation. // like that i am passing
  
});
```

In my component, I am using this state like this:

```
{{localized.edit}}



...mapState(module_name, ['localized']),
```

But, it is showing error. So, how can I use it properly for static texts?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem like something that should live in your store as it's just a helper constant, not `state`.

In your component simply `import translation from '@/path/helpers.js`

Then use `translation.edit`.

Additionally if you did want it to live in your store then you're trying to use it as `translation.` instead of how it should be: `translation`. (Without the `.`)

Comment: Can you tell me briefly how to set this to state and use it into component?

Comment: without dot notation how can i get the particular key?

Comment: @user7411584 you can always use the `['key']` syntax.

Comment: @user7411584 why do you think this needs to be set to state though? It's not dynamic. Unless you are talking about binding a particular _value_ to a piece of state... in which case you can just do `state.myValue = translation.edit`